# Add breaks after each element via query

Tags: jquery

I have a code:

```
<span class="twolastbuttons">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a>
  </div>
</span>
```

I am trying to add **< BR >** tag after each **< A >** using jquery, but no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.btn-group a').after('<br>');
```

Or alternatively this other way too:

```
$('<br>').insertAfter('.btn-group a');
```

Comment: thanks! it seems something was wrong in my realisation, because I also tried to use .after().

Answer (score 2):

Do this way:

```
$('.btn-group a').each(function() {
    $("<br/>").insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/JRVtU/1/)** and for more information on **[.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) - [Click here](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)**